# GitPython Unable to Find Head Commit

Tags: git, python-3.x, gitpython

I want to get the commit object of my repo's HEAD. When I try to call `repo.head.commit` however, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\refs\symbolic.py", line 200, in _get_commit
    obj = self._get_object()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\refs\symbolic.py", line 193, in _get_object
    return Object.new_from_sha(self.repo, hex_to_bin(self.dereference_recursive(self.repo, self.path)))
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\objects\base.py", line 64, in new_from_sha
    oinfo = repo.odb.info(sha1)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\db.py", line 37, in info
    hexsha, typename, size = self._git.get_object_header(bin_to_hex(sha))
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 1073, in get_object_header
    return self.__get_object_header(cmd, ref)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 1062, in __get_object_header
    return self._parse_object_header(cmd.stdout.readline())
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 1024, in _parse_object_header
    raise ValueError("SHA could not be resolved, git returned: %r" % (header_line.strip()))
ValueError: SHA could not be resolved, git returned: b''
```

Calling `repo.head.commit` a second time (and every time afterwards), I then get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\refs\symbolic.py", line 200, in _get_commit
    obj = self._get_object()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\refs\symbolic.py", line 193, in _get_object
    return Object.new_from_sha(self.repo, hex_to_bin(self.dereference_recursive(self.repo, self.path)))
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\objects\base.py", line 64, in new_from_sha
    oinfo = repo.odb.info(sha1)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\db.py", line 37, in info
    hexsha, typename, size = self._git.get_object_header(bin_to_hex(sha))
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 1073, in get_object_header
    return self.__get_object_header(cmd, ref)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 1061, in __get_object_header
    cmd.stdin.flush()
```

Additional Information:
`repo.head` -> `<git.HEAD "HEAD">`

I'm on a Windows 10 environment. This may be related to another question of mine:
[Git Not Working with Ubuntu -> Windows Samba Shared Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513149/git-not-working-with-ubuntu-windows-samba-shared-directory)

Answer (score 3):

Initializing the `repo` object like this worked for me:

```
import git

repo = git.Repo('.', odbt=git.db.GitDB)
```

It seems there might be some caveats to this solution though. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/642#issuecomment-618117030).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was arising from my directory being located on a UNC path and was fixed by updating my git version.

[Git not working with Ubuntu → Windows Samba shared directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513149/git-not-working-with-ubuntu-%E2%86%92-windows-samba-shared-directory)